# Django query across many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to retrieve the following data in a view:

`user_profile` has a one-to-one join to `users`
`user_profile` has a many-to-many join to `store`, via the `stores` field
`store` has a one-to-many join to `targets`, via `targets.store`

I can retrieve all stores associated with a user by doing:

```
user_profile = request.user.get_profile()
all_stores = user_profile.stores.all()
```

What I'd like to retrieve is all targets associated with the user ID of `user_profile`, presumably via the `all_stores` result, but I'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

Comment: @S.Lott, yes, but I haven't been able to create the query; I'm not sure how I should be defining the filter statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Target.objects.filter( store__user_profile__user=request.user )
```

Comment: Thanks. I was getting confused by trying to follow the relationship backwards/forwards, instead of thinking in terms of a SQL join.